# Profile issues on Gaming Meta?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-profile

I would like to change some profile information, or at least copy it from StackOverflow. There's no option to do this, nor is there an Accounts tab.

I changed my profile on Gaming just fine, but the changes haven't taken place on Meta quite yet.

Is this by design?

Comment: Covered somewhat in: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/203/weird-profile-behavior-on-meta-gaming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Profiles are synced between parent and child metas every hour; this should be working now!

If you absolutely, positively must see your changes take effect *right now* then log off and log back on.